# Python 3 Classes, using kivy module

Tags: python-3.x, class, kivy

I don't have a lot of experience with classes, but i needed to create a project using it, so I had to do it. The problem is i got lost with 'self', because in the function 'AddToDo' i want to append to the list from '**init**' function, but it says 'Button' object has no attribute 'to_dos'. So how can i append in a list 'to_dos'? I need to also note that this code is really simplified.

```
    class ToDoList(FloatLayout):
    
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super(ToDoList,self).__init__(**kwargs)

            with open('todolist_demo.json','r') as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                self.to_dos = data

            to_do_but = Button()
            to_do_but.bind(on_press=ToDoList.CreateToDo)  
            self.add_widget(to_do_but)

        def CreateToDo(self):
            but = Button()

            def AddToDo(self):

                self.to_dos.append(9)

            but.bind(on_press=AddToDo)
            self.add_widget(but)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your AtddToDo looks fine, but you do have a problem that `on_press=ToDoList.CreateToDo` should be `on_press=self.CeateToDo`

Answer (score 0):

I included this in my own project and it worked for me, but had trouble finding the AddToDo function so I pulled it up, here is the code:

```
    class ToDoList(FloatLayout):
    
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super(ToDoList,self).__init__(**kwargs)

            f = open('todolist_demo.json','r')
            data = json.load(f)

            self.to_dos = data

            to_do_but = Button()
            to_do_but.bind(on_press=ToDoList.CreateToDo)  
            self.add_widget(to_do_but)

        def AddToDo(self):
            self.to_dos.append(9)

        def CreateToDo(self):
            but = Button()
            but.bind(on_press=AddToDo)
            self.add_widget(but)
```

If it doesn't work for you, I have to ask you to discard your full code.